# Redis localhost limitations and costs

Tags: redis

I downloaded Redis server and cli to my local machine and it working good.

I just wanted to know if I can use it also in production server:

Are there any critical limitations? For example: Can I use 100 GB for free? (It will be on my computer).

I know that Redis labs cost money per month but if I download the redis to my machine and not using the redis labs, would it be free? (and the cost will be only the storage of the machine I using).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis is an open source software, licensed under BSD. That basically means you can do anything you want with it, without owing anyone anything.

Redis Labs, the home of open source Redis and the provider of commercial products that leverage on it, offers a wide spectrum of solutions - whether hosted, as-a-service, downloadable, remotely managed and so forth. You can (and should sometimes) use them, but that's definitely not a requirement.

Disclaimer: I work at Redis Labs and with the open source project.